# Translate Typescript to Java

Tags: java, typescript, code-translation

I'm trying to change a code that is in Typescript into Java. I really don't know much about Typescript and got stuck on this function. I reduced the code into a simpler case. In this case `CustomType1` and `CustomType2` are just custom "export types" (which I implemented in Java as classes).

```
proof(): CustomType1 | 'given' | undefined {
    if (something) {
        return 'given'
    }

    const evidence = ... //Set to a new "instance" of CustomType2
    return evidence ? function(evidence) : undefined //Function returns an "instance" of CustomType1
}
```

Then, the previous code is run at some point like this

```
const proof = proof()
if (!proof || proof === 'given') {
    //...
}
```

I would appreciate if someone explains to me, how does this code on Typescript works.

What does the `?` stand for? And what does the proof() function returns... an instance of Customtype1? the string "given"? both? And finally, when calling `!proof`, what does it stand for? because I don't see any boolean value in any part.

Comment: There is a way too much pseudo-code here, imo. You should reduce this question to a reproducible example that we can run ourselves.

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: @Rubydesic I just need an explanation of what does the proof() function returns... it's really a problem of understanding Typescript syntaxes. But I'll edit.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I know...

Comment: Please read about typescript's union types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Q:** What does `?` stand for?

   **A:** It is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
2. **Q:** What does the proof() function return?

   **A:** It returns any one of the following: a `CustomType1`, the literal string `'given'`, or `undefined`. Specifically, it is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).
3. **Q:** When calling `!proof`, what does it stand for?

   **A:** Note that something tricky is going on in your example code. The local variable `const proof` is [shadowing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-shadowing-in-javascript/), i.e. replacing in the current scope, the original `proof`function. The code would be more clearly written as

   ```
    const result = proof()
    if (!result || result === 'given') {
        //...
    }
   ```

   This code is mostly functionally equivalent. Here, `!result` is `true` if `result` is a [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. Most pertinent to this case, it's `true` if `result === undefined`